# Question on convergence of indicator functions by means of Hausdorff distance convergence of the sets

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, characteristic-functions, hausdorff-distance

My question arises [from the attached post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3571349/does-convergence-in-hausdorf-distance-tell-us-something-about-weak-convergence) . In this post, it is mentioned that no convergence (not even a weak one) of indicator functions can be deduced from the convergence of the sets in the sense of Hausdorff distance.

> However, I wonder the following. If we could impose some extra condition ( maybe on the sets), then would the convergence of the
> corresponding indicator functions be true?

I already tried to google this but nothing useful showed up, so I thought to ask here.

Many thanks in advance!